# PHP mbstring loaded in cli but not in web

Tags: php, lighttpd, mbstring

I am trying to install phpMyAdmin on a CentOs 6 system with lighttpd and php 5.3.3. The problem is that the mbstring module is not loaded. I checked the /etc/php.d/mbstring.ini file and the line is not commented. Also added the line from this file to the php.ini. Still not loading. phpinfo() also does not show that it includes the mbstring.ini file. But when I run php -i it is included and mbstring loaded.

phpinfo():

```
Additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php.d/curl.ini, /etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini, /etc/php.d/json.ini, /etc/php.d/lighttpd.ini, /etc/php.d/mysql.ini, /etc/php.d/mysqli.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini, /etc/php.d/phar.ini, /etc/php.d/sqlite3.ini, /etc/php.d/zip.ini
```

php -i :

```
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php.d/bcmath.ini,
/etc/php.d/curl.ini,
/etc/php.d/dom.ini,
/etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php.d/gd.ini,
/etc/php.d/json.ini,
/etc/php.d/lighttpd.ini,
/etc/php.d/mbstring.ini,
/etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php.d/phar.ini,
/etc/php.d/sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php.d/tidy.ini,
/etc/php.d/wddx.ini,
/etc/php.d/xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php.d/xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php.d/xsl.ini,
/etc/php.d/zip.ini
```

Comment: Is the extension installed? `php -m |grep mbstring`  It comes from the RPM `php-mbstring`.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski yes it is installed

Comment: cli and web modules usually have different php.ini files. Maybe those include a different selection of files. Did you compare those base php.ini files?

Comment: @ToBe No but from php -i and phpinfo() the same dir is scanned see my answer for a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really silly I just had to restart the server it works perfectly now.